# covariance of quadratic form in general

Tags: probability, covariance

Let $\mathbf{w}\sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{\Sigma})$, and $\mathbf{A, B}$ are symmetric matrices, then it is known that

$ \operatorname{Cov}\left[\mathbf{w^TAw, w^TBw}\right]=2\operatorname{Tr}[\mathbf{A\Sigma B\Sigma}].$

The problem is to compute

$\operatorname{Cov}\left[\mathbf{w^TAw, v^TBv}\right]$, where $\mathbf{w, v}\sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{\Sigma})$, and $\mathbf{A, B}$ are symmetric matrices.

Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any reference for the result you are trying to prove? I think I've seen that result in the isotropic case i.e. $\mathbf{w} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2 I)$, it has the same structure as $2 \operatorname{Tr}[\mathbf{A}\mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{B}\mathbf{\Sigma}]$ but it uses isotropy to prove $2 \sigma^4 \operatorname{Tr}[\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}]$. The main reason being an inspection on $E[\mathbf{w}_i \mathbf{w}_j \mathbf{w}_k \mathbf{w}_l]$ where $\mathbf{w}_i$ is the ith component of $\mathbf{w}$.